# Replace numbers with an asterisk in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, replace, nsstring, character

I have an NSString that contains the user's credit card number. I want to replace the numbers to asterisk. How can I do that? I think the code below won't work since it only targets one number:

```
finalString = [[firstString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"O" withString:@"*"] stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"o" withString:@"0"];
```

Doing a for loop on all the numbers is the best thing to do here or there's another way? TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSCharacterSet* charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
 finalString = [[finalString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet] componentsJoinedByString:@"*"];
```

Comment: What if I just want to replace the first 12 characters of the 16 digit card number?

Answer (score 2):

You may also use regular expressions for such tasks:
(using the RegExKitLite)

```
 NSString * regex = @"[0-9]";
 NSString * stringWithAsteriskInsteadOfNumbers = [stringWithNumbers stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regex withString:@"*"];
```

Comment: No such thing as `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex`. Not recognized by xcode. May be it was ... 9 years ago

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way, without allocating zillions of objects:

```
NSRegularExpression* e = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d" 
                             options:0 error:nil];
finalString = [e stringByReplacingMatchesInString:finalString
                                          options:0 
                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [finalString length]) 
                                     withTemplate:@"*"];
```